# how to set back textbox value to its binding source in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a textbox for which I have set the object binding source of a Customer.Name property
On load, when I set the bindingSource = Customer, the value of Customer.Name gets assigned textbox on the windows form.
On Save what should I do to save the changes from the textbox to Customer.Name

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically. If you wish it to happen earlier, then change the data source update mode (in Databindings -> Advanced...) from `OnValidation` to `OnPropertyChanged`.